# setAccessoryType destroys TableViewCell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I use a custom tablecell, labels and images are connected with tags.

If i add

> [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator]

it destroys my tableview. the image destroys and the background-color.

here are the differences:

[image] [image]

Does anyone have any idea where the problem could be?
Thanks

EDIT:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        if ([self labelCellNib]) {
            [[self labelCellNib] instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
        } else {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LabelCell" owner:self options:nil];
        }

        cell = self.labelCell;
        self.labelCell = nil;
    }

    static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = nil;
    if (dateFormatter == nil)
        dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    static NSCalendar *calendar;
    if(calendar == nil)
        calendar= [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSString * timeStampString = [sqlTime objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSTimeInterval _interval=[timeStampString doubleValue];
    NSDate *createdAt = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:_interval];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];

    // Datum in die Tabellen-Zelle einfügen
    UILabel *label4 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:LABEL4];
    label4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:createdAt]];

    // Configure the cell...
    UILabel *label1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:LABEL1];
    label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [sqlData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], sonderzeichen];

    UILabel *label2 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:LABEL2];
    label2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Preis pro %@: %@ €", sonderzeichen, [sqlPreis objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    UILabel *label3 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:LABEL3];
    UIImageView *image = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:IMAGE_TAG];

    if (indexPath.row==[itemsArray count]-1) {
        image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"];
        label3.text = @"-";
    } else if ([itemsArray count]>1) {
        int data_old = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [sqlData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] intValue];
        int data_new = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [sqlData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+1]] intValue];
        label3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", data_old-data_new];

        NSLog(@"%d -- %d", data_old, data_new);
        if (data_new>data_old) {
            image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pfeil_runter.png"];
        } else if (data_new<data_old) {
            image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pfeil_hoch.png"];
        } else {
            image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"minus.png"];
        }
    }

    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = indexPath.row % 2? [UIColor colorWithRed:228.0/255.0 green:244.0/255.0 blue:199.0/255.0 alpha:1]:[UIColor whiteColor];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: How are you adding the labels and images to your cells? Please post cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: You should move all dynamic content from cellForRowAtIndexPath to willDisplayCell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the background color of the cell, rather than the contentView, but this doesn't work in cellForRowAtIndexPath. It needs to be in willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = indexPath.row % 2? [UIColor colorWithRed:228.0/255.0 green:244.0/255.0 blue:199.0/255.0 alpha:1]:[UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

As far as the images getting squashed, that has to do with the size of your subviews, and their constraints. I think you can fix those by giving width constraints to two of your labels (a pair over and under each other), but make their priority <1000, so when the accessory view is added, the width of those labels will get smaller. Also give the image view on the left a fixed width.

Comment: Ok this with the images runs! but the background color doesn't work with the willDisplayCell Code

Comment: @Loko, You changed it to cell.backgroundColor not cell.contentView.backgroundColor? I've test this, and it worked fine for me.